# .. topics that I should ( be looking / look ) into more deeply

Tags: modal-verbs, comparison, complements, progressive-aspect

> This time is also the perfect opportunity for me to think over my final project and consider topics that I should ( **be looking / look** ) into more deeply.

Which one is more common ? could you tell me the differences?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either one is perfectly valid.  I don't know that one is more common than the other, I can imagine people using either variation frequently.

The minor difference is that "be looking" implies that you should be looking *now*, as well as in the future.

"...I should *look* into more deeply" gives the impression that you are only referring to the future, and ignoring the present.